# How can I make a 'notification' sound play when a webpage is opened on an Android phone?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I've been searching today and have found some answers, such as this:

```
<head>
    <title>Audio test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // @param filename The name of the file WITHOUT ending
        function playSound(filename){   
            document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML='<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="' + filename + '.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /><source src="' + filename + '.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /><embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" src="' + filename +'.mp3" /></audio>';
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="playSound('bing');">Play</button>  
    <div id="sound"></div>

</body>
```

For the answer above, I believe I just need to enter the correct file name (ex. mydomain.com/correctfilename.mp3) where 'filename' is in that script.

But I'm looking for something a little different and a little faster load-time wise. I'm wondering if I can have a 'default' Android notification sound played when the site is opened. I've found something similar to what I need right here:

```
try {
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),     notification);
    r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I put that in the HTML file, it doesn't work, and I think it's because it's not javascript.

I know there are ways to access whatever your phone has that makes it vibrate, so I'm thinking there could be a way to access the pre-loaded sounds it has. Can I do this with a script?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if you can do something from the web page, not from a specific app on the device - for that way use [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

For any web page to access device services via the browser, there is the [W3C Device API Working Group](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/), which has produced a [Vibration API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-vibration-20150210/), and even [works already on Android Chrome Beta 39](https://w3c.github.io/test-results/vibration/20141118.html) and others like so:

```
navigator.vibrate(2000);
```

I'm not aware, however, of some way to play a default sound/vibration that follows the device environment like say, [Windows API handles it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Media.SystemSounds_properties(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: OK thank you. I actually figured out an easier way to do what I wanted: 1. Download a notification mp3 form an app (zedge). 2. upload it to itunes. 3. compress file size down from 27kb to ~5kb in itunes. 4. upload it to my site (still having a little trouble having it autoplay without the play button toolbar thing, but I think I'll get there)